# Rotate object using Sin and Cos using Time.deltaTime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I would like to know how an object can be moved using time.deltaTime when it should only be able to be moved on a circle.

In this case, I'm dealing with a camera that rotates around the player.

```
    _GoalX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    float y = _PlayerHeight;
    float x = Mathf.Cos(_GoalX);
    float z = Mathf.Sin(_GoalX);
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

The camera should not be placed immediately at the destinal position, but over time, moving on the circle around the player.

I can not use Vector3.Lerp(startvector,targetvector) because then the camera might get into the player.

Comment: You will have to do something like `position = (player.x + distance * cos(phi), player.y + heightOfCameraAbovePlayer, player.z + distance * sin(phi))`.(pseudocode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In update you can it do like this:

```
void update(){
angle += RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
Vector3 offset = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(_angle)* xRadius, _PlayerHeight, Mathf.Cos(_angle)* zRadius);
transform.position = _centre + offset;
}
```